# Extjs4 Sass - Gradients - Mixin

Tags: extjs4

I'm trying to using SASS with ExtJS 4 but some variables aren't working.

My SASS config:

```
    # $ext_path: This should be the path of where the ExtJS SDK is installed
    # Generally this will be in a lib/extjs folder in your applications root
    # <root>/lib/extjs
    $ext_path = "../lib/extjs"

    # sass_path: the directory your Sass files are in. THIS file should also be in the Sass folder
    # Generally this will be in a resources/sass folder
    # <root>/resources/sass
    sass_path = File.dirname(__FILE__)

    # css_path: the directory you want your CSS files to be.
    # Generally this is a folder in the parent directory of your Sass files
    # <root>/resources/css
    css_path = File.join(sass_path, "..", "_css")

    # output_style: The output style for your compiled CSS
    # nested, expanded, compact, compressed
    output_style = :expanded

    # We need to load in the Ext4 themes folder, which includes all it's default styling, images, variables and mixins
    load File.join(sass_path, '..','resources','themes')
```

And this is my SCSS File:

```
    // Wenn man alle Komponenten einbinden möchte, muss die Variabel $include-default auf true gestellt werden
    // Wenn diese auf true stehen sollte, könnte man die Einzel-Includes entfernen 
    $include-default: false;

    // Theme Name:
    $theme-name: 'MyTheme';

    // Custom Variabeln:
    $base-color: #ffe067; /* Hauptfarbe */
    $color: #595959; /* Text Standard Farbe */
    $font-size: 12px; /* Text Standard Größe */
    $font-family: arial,verdana,sans-serif; /* Text Standard Art */
    $base-gradient: 'glossy';
    $background-color: #ff0000;
    $ui-header-background-color: #ff0000;
    $ui-header-background-gradient: green;
    $ui-header-inner-border-color: #ff0000;
    $background-color-over: #ff0000;
    $background-gradient-over: #ff0000;
    $background-color-focus: #ff0000;
    $background-gradient-focus: #ff0000;
    $background-color-pressed: #ff0000;
    $background-gradient-pressed: #ff0000;
    $background-color-disabled: #ff0000;
    $background-gradient-disabled: #ff0000;


    @import 'ext4/default/all';

    // Einzelne Module können entfernt werden, falls diese nicht benötigt werden,
    // dies kann man machen um die CSS zu minimieren
    @include extjs-boundlist;
    @include extjs-button;
    @include extjs-btn-group;
    @include extjs-datepicker;
    @include extjs-colorpicker;
    @include extjs-menu;
    @include extjs-grid;
    @include extjs-form;
        @include extjs-form-field;
        @include extjs-form-fieldset;
        @include extjs-form-checkboxfield;
        @include extjs-form-checkboxgroup;
        @include extjs-form-triggerfield;
        @include extjs-form-htmleditor;
    @include extjs-panel;
    @include extjs-qtip;
    @include extjs-slider;
    @include extjs-progress;
    @include extjs-toolbar;
    @include extjs-window;
    @include extjs-messagebox;
    @include extjs-tabbar;
    @include extjs-tab;
    @include extjs-tree;
    @include extjs-drawcomponent;
    @include extjs-viewport;
```

The variables like `$base-color` and `$font-size` are working, but `$background-color` doesn't work. Any tips?

Answer (score 2):

All variables that have been pre-defined for use are located in the `/extjs4/resources/themes/stylesheets/ext4/default/variables` folder. There are several files there with many different variables per each one. You should look through these files carefully and ensure that the variables above are actually in there.

Additionally, the `widgets` folder contains the ui mixin definitions. These are useful as well, and they are applied a bit differently than a variable.

The following guide: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/guide/theming contains more detailed information, and would likely be helpful.

Comment: Thank you for your help and informations. I got the variables like "$base-color" from those file: resources\themes\stylesheets\ext4\default\mixins\_background-gradient.scss

Comment: To clarify this further. You are trying to change the variables that are used inside the mixins for widgets. You need to find the variables used as parameters to those mixins and change them in your theme file.

Answer (score 0):

In the file comments: /**
 * @mixin background-gradient
 * @param {Color} $background-color The background color of the gradient
So i tried to use $background-gradient and $bg-color without any change..